# Find all $n$ such that $\phi(n)/n=1/2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $\phi$ be the Euler's phi function.I want to find those $n$ for which $\frac{\phi(n)}{n}=1/2$.I know that $n=2^k$ will work.But can we show that these are the only integers such that this holds?

**Addendum**

I have tried to show like this,$n=2^\alpha p_1^{\alpha_1}...p_k^{\alpha_k}$,where $p_1,...,p_k$ are odd prime divisors ,then $\phi(n)=2^{\alpha-1}p_1^{\alpha-1}...p_k^{\alpha_k-1}(p_1-1)...(p_k-1)$.So,$\phi(n)/n=\frac{(p_1-1)...(p_k-1)}{2p_1p_2...p_k}$,now  $2$ gets cancelled with  $2 $ in $(p_1-1)$ and thus denominator cannot contain $2$ in reduced form.

Comment: Consider how the prime decomposition of $n$ relates to the value of $\frac{\phi(n)}n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to do this without factoring into primes, note that $\phi(n)$ is always an integer, so in order to have $\phi(n)=n/2$, $n$ must be even. But in that case the only numbers less than $n$ relatively prime to $n$ are *odd* numbers, which means *all* of them must be relatively prime to $n$. So $n$ cannot be divisible by any odd prime. Thus $n$ must be a power of $2$.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 2):

Factorize $n$ as $p_1^{e_1}...p_k^{e_k}$. Since
$$
  \varphi (n) = n \prod_{i=1}^{k}\left( 1-\frac{1}{p_i} \right)  \implies \frac{\varphi (n)}{n} =\prod_{i=1}^{k} \left( 1-\frac{1}{p_i} \right) ,   
$$
it suffices to show that the product is never $1 /2$ when $n$ contains prime factors other than $2$. Indeed, assuming all $p_i$'s are odd, from
$$
  \prod_{i=1}^{k} \left( 1-\frac{1}{p_i} \right)  =  \frac{\prod_{i=1}^{k} (p_i-1)}{\prod_{i=1}^{k} p_i}
$$

we see that $2^{k}$ divides the numerator whereas the denominator is odd. Clearly this ratio can never be $1 /2$. (The case where one of them is $2$ is analogous; the denominator still cannot contain more powers of $2$.)

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Suppose $p_1,p_2,..., p_k$ are the distinct prime factors of $n$ then by Euler's formula for $\phi(n)$ we will have
$$ p_1 p_2\ldots p_k = 2 (p_1-1)\ldots (p_k-1)$$

Now try to see that if $p_i \ne 2$ then $2$ divides $p_i -1$. Now count the highest power of $2$ in both sides.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).